# Checking C code according to Matlab

Tags: c, algorithm, matlab

1. I have a linear algebra algorithm written in Matlab and this code runs correctly.
2. I have implemented the same algorithm in C for obtaining better performance.
3. However, my C code has bugs.
4. In order to find bugs, I visually compare matrices generated by the two implementations at each step of the algorithm.

Is there a better way to compare output of Matlab and C codes? I have to work close to machine precision.

Comment: First link if you google for [matlab c](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Comment: Create a toy example, short inputs, maybe just a few samples of `ones`, `zeros`, ramps (`1:n`) etc. Try to 'turn off' parts of the code and/or print intermediate results to narrow down the problem. Also if dealing with fractions be careful how you compared use `abs(MatlabOut-COut)<Precision` instead of `MatlabOut==COut`.